# I want to create an image database for a gallery that can be publically accessed via our website. Is this something Salesforce can do?

Tags: images

I want to create an image database for a gallery's website. The images should be clickable with various information (artist, year, etc) showing up once clicked. Certain information like price, owner, etc should not be visible to the public but should be visible to the gallery internally. Is this something Salesforce is good at doing or should I use a completely different web software for this?

Answer (score 1):

Can you do it? Yes, most definitely. By creating a public Site, you can create a portal that is driven by standard or custom objects, and you can control visibility of the records and fields using Sharing Settings, Field Level Security, Profile Permissions, and more. Images can be stored in Salesforce and exposed in a controlled fashion to the outside world. You can even set up a custom domain name and link it to your Site so that visitors are not even (explicitly) aware that they're using Salesforce. You can see a list of companies that built sites in the [Sites.com Gallery](http://developer.force.com/sitesgallery). Obviously, this list is non-exhaustive, but by looking at the wide range of the sites, you can get the idea that a lot of things are possible. Some look very "Salesforce-y" in nature, and others you'd have no idea were running on Salesforce at all without actually looking at obvious markers like cookies. A basic site could be up in just a few hours, but the more time you put in to it, the more it'll feel like your own. Note that there [daily limits](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sites_limits.htm&type=5) to the resources you can use for free, but these are upgradeable if you get enough traffic to justify it.